# Finding a gap in an ordered range of adjacent numbers

Tags: algorithm, search

This is a homework exercise from Steven Skiena's "The algorithm design manual" 2nd edition, p 143.

> Suppose that you are given a sorted sequence of distinct integers `{A1,A2,...An}`, drawn from `1` to `m` where `n < m`.  Give an `O(lgN)` algorithm to find an integer `<= m` that is not present in `A`.  For full credit, find the smallest such integer.

A sorted sequence, and `O(lgN)` both suggest a binary search algorithm. The only way I could think of is to run through numbers from `1` through `m`, and for each number do a binary search to see if it exists in sequence `A`. But that means `O(mlgN)`, not really `O(lgN)`.

Comment: This is an old brainteaser. Hint: Sum(1..N) = N(N+1)/2.

Comment: @DiegoBasch That hint is for a different problem. In this problem, there can be more than one missing number. Hint for this problem: If no numbers are missing, then `A[i]=i`.

Comment: The way I'm thinking about it, my hint works for this problem too.

Comment: that's a dichotomic search with a comparison between the element and its rank.

Answer (score 5):

There is an integer less than `A[k]` missing if and only if

```
A[k] > k
```

(using 1-based indexing).

So to find the smallest missing number, binary search. Start with the middle index `m`. If `A[m] > m`, then there is a number smaller than `A[m]` missing, search in the left half. Otherwise, if `A[m] == m`, there is no smaller number than `m` missing, and you search the right half.