# What is the most efficient datastructure for an ordered sequence with gaps search and append only?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I need to store a set of ordered integers which can form sequences like the following

```
1,2,3,15,16,20,21,25,26,27,28
```

It can also be represented as

```
1-3,15-16,20-21,25-28
```

I don't need the sequences to be ordered I just need to be able to add integers and know if some integer is in the *set*.

I'm looking for datastructure that is fast `O(lg(n))` or `O(n*lg(n))` in terms of insertion and *search* ie. is X in the set of integers, that can handle concurrent read-write and if possible write-write without locks and without persistence.

For same insertion and search time, the more space efficient solution will be choosen.

A binary search tree but it is not good enough because since integers are inserted in ever growing ascending orderd the generated tree doesn't look good, so I think I need a multiversion self balancing tree.

There is no duplicates.

No code is needed just an explanation with references will do the job.

Background: This is for a mvcc database, each transaction has a transaction id which should be unique while being ordered ie. for two T1(t1), T2(t2), id(T1) < id(T2). The gaps comes from the fact a transaction doesn't commit its transaction id is lost. Transaction ids are used to annotate data versions, to know if a version of a data should be considered and how, you must know at least if it's commited for that I must maintain a list of commited transaction, a hash map of intergers can do the job perfectly for a POC but not in the long run. I don't know how professionnal dbs do that...

Similar question which can be a bit misleading: [Finding a gap in an ordered range of adjacent numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793764/finding-a-gap-in-an-ordered-range-of-adjacent-numbers/15316552#15316552)

Comment: what programming language?

Comment: 1) Sounds like a standard balanced BST (e.g. Red-Black tree / AVL tree). With a little added complexity, you can even have a node represent an interval (not quite an interval tree) (though that may mess with the balancing a little). Concurrency for these are not difficult to deal with. 2) What do you mean by "integers are inserted in order"? If you mean just during construction, then I believe there are methods to construct a perfectly balanced BST in O(n) time given a sorted set of numbers.

Comment: The most space-efficient data structure will probably be a Judy-tree, but updates can become quite costly. Just like interval/range trees, concurrency may require range-locks (or maybe even a tree of them ...)

Comment: how does it handle duplicates?

Comment: @Dukeling 1) I will investigate that thx.  2) it's an always growing list of integers there is not duplicates but there might be gaps

Comment: @Moop There is no duplicates just gaps in the intervals

Comment: @omerschleifer Python, C or Java if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) -- that's an amended binary search tree that compresses intervals. The problem of ordered insertion can be handled by using a self-balancing variant. Concurrency support can be achieved either with locks or by implementing a [persistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) version.

Comment: I'm considering your answer, I'm just need time to properly understand the interval tree, it's close to an algorithm that I had, I still need to make it work. Also I updated the question to specify that persistence is not a possible solution for achieving concurrency and locks are last resort solution.

Comment: @amirouche: why is persistence not an option? And: are we talking about the same kind of persistence? Please read the Wikipedia article that I referred to; this type of persistence is ideal in parallel and concurrent programming.