# Testing reliability of a stream by identifying gaps in a sequence

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stream, gaps-and-islands

I'm working on a problem that I think reduces to the following and was hoping to find data structures or algorithms that can solve it in a memory-efficient manner.

Say you're reading from a (infinite) steam of sequence numbers. Some producer is emitting numbers into this stream consecutively with no repetition and you read them from the other end. However there are a couple of problems.

1.) There is something about this system is inherently unreliable. Either the stream or producer or something in-between can drop a piece of data so numbers may not appear at the consumer, and overall there is a (unknown) probability `p` that any given number may be lost.

2.) The stream does not guarantee order perfectly. For sake of argument let's say there is some (well known) constant `N` such that if you read a number `x` from the stream, you can be certain that you will never see a number `y < x - N` from the stream after that point.

That is to say, the sequence of numbers can only ever be `N` values "out of order" at any time.

I'd really like to identify `p` in this case. Or a reasonable estimate of `p` is all that matters.

I'd appreciate any references to relevant data structures or algorithms that would help solve this in a memory-efficient manner. Some brief pseudocode would be helpful as well. Thanks!

**EDIT:** By memory efficient I mean I am hoping to be able to solve this problem without having to use O(N) memory where N is the number of entries I read from the stream.

Comment: I did find this question that is similar (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323362/what-is-the-most-efficient-datastructure-for-an-ordered-sequence-with-gaps-searc) but I'm not sure how to employ the out-of-order issue.

Comment: You want to come up with a reasonable estimate of `p` based only on this description? Or you want to determine the value of `p` based on some sample of data received?

Comment: @JimMischel By sampling the data; I don't believe you could estimate `p` by only what I said. That would be impressive though.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward approach can be as follows.

Assume you listen for the stream for a long enough time, and the last number you have read is `x`. Then you know that all the numbers less that `x-N` are either already received either lost. If you store all the numbers received, you can easily find out how many numbers less than `x-N` you have already *actually* received; let's say you have actually received `A` numbers. And you definitely know<sup>*</sup> how many numbers less than `x-N` you were *expecting* to receive, let's say you were expecting to receive `B` numbers. The ratio of these two values, `A/B`, will give you a good estimate of `p`.

<sup>*</sup> This depends on whether you know the first number that you should have received. If, for example, you know that the sequence starts from `0`, then you should have expected `B=x-N` numbers. If you do not know the starting number, you can limit it similarly to what I have described above by taking the very first number received, `z`, and considering only the numbers between `z+N` and `x-N`.

---

To be able to find `A` you can use many data structures. A binary search tree is an obvious choice. Or you can only store the total number received and the `N` largest numbers ever received, for this the BST is also a good option.